# Attaching WndProc in WPF Page

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying tot attaching WndProc in WPF `Page`, not `Window`.

I am using this example:

http://blog.andreweichacker.com/2010/02/attaching-to-wndproc-in-wpf/

But it does not work for WPF `Page`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because wndproc is a Windows concept, and is per window.  It knows nothing about WPF pages which are constructs internal to WPF. Window is the only thing with a wndproc.

Comment: I believe it is possible, but i really don't how?

Comment: Can I write a class library to detect hardware changes.

Comment: Perhaps if you explained exactly what you're trying to achieve?